# Exception safety issue of std::make_unique()

Tags: c++, exception, c++14, unique-ptr, std

From this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49646113/1348273), we know that the following code is exception-safe (assuming that `T( U(std::move(v)) )` is exception-safe, e.g., does not throw, which is library user's responsibility).

```
auto p = new T( U(std::move(v)) );
```

The key point here is that the initializer expression `U(std::move(v))` is evaluated after memory allocation. Now consider the `std::make_unique()` counterpart.

```
auto p = std::make_unique<T>( U(std::move(v)) );
```

The initializer expression `U(std::move(v))` is evaluated even before `std::make_unique()` is called. If memory allocation failed thereafter, `v` would have already been moved/modified, providing no strong exception safety. However, if we write

```
std::unique_ptr<T> p(new T( U(std::move(v)) ));
```

The new-expression mechanism kicks-in, and we regain strong exception safety. Looks like an exception-safe `make_unique` has to be a macro.

```
#define MAKE_UNIQUE(T, ...) ::std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(__VA_ARGS__))
```

I'm new to exception safety and wondering whether my reasoning is correct. And if so, if there a better solution than the macro above?

Comment: And what if the `&&` constructor of `U` throws? Or the constructor of `T` that takes a `U` throws? If either one throws, then the move already happened and `v` has been moved-from. So no strong exception safety.

Comment: @NicolBolas Updated question. The goal here is that so long as `T(U&&)` is exception-safe (which is the user's responsibility), the code should be exception-safe.

Comment: Keep in mind that `std::move` doesn't actually move anything, nor does it even compile into actual executable code.

Comment: @Lingxi: There is a difference between "exception-safe" and the "strong exception guarantee".

Comment: What do you mean *exception-safe* there is no such word in the standard.