# Issue of `if constexpr` with non-placement new

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, if-constexpr, new-expression

I'm trying to write a utility that invokes either `new T{...}` or `new T(...)` based on whether `T` is an aggregate type. What I have reached so far is as follows. Note that I'm using a macro instead of a function template because of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49684684/1348273).

```
#define MAKE(p, T, ...) \
  T* p; \
  if constexpr (::std::is_aggregate_v<T>) { \
    p = new T{__VA_ARGS__}; \
  } \
  else { \
    p = new T(__VA_ARGS__); \
  }
```

I tried to test it on gcc 7.2.0 with

```
struct pr_t {
  int a, b;
};

int main() {
  MAKE(p, pr_t, 1, 2);
}
```

The following error then occurred ([live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nM1HO8bsSePn4z4m)).

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:9:26: error: new initializer expression list treated as compound expression [-fpermissive]
     p = new T(__VA_ARGS__); \
                          ^
prog.cc:17:3: note: in expansion of macro 'MAKE'
   MAKE(p, pr_t, 1, 2);
   ^~~~
prog.cc:9:26: warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]
     p = new T(__VA_ARGS__); \
                          ^
prog.cc:17:3: note: in expansion of macro 'MAKE'
   MAKE(p, pr_t, 1, 2);
   ^~~~
prog.cc:9:26: error: no matching function for call to 'pr_t::pr_t(int)'
     p = new T(__VA_ARGS__); \
                          ^
prog.cc:17:3: note: in expansion of macro 'MAKE'
   MAKE(p, pr_t, 1, 2);
   ^~~~
prog.cc:12:8: note: candidate: pr_t::pr_t()
 struct pr_t {
        ^~~~
prog.cc:12:8: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
prog.cc:12:8: note: candidate: constexpr pr_t::pr_t(const pr_t&)
prog.cc:12:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'int' to 'const pr_t&'
prog.cc:12:8: note: candidate: constexpr pr_t::pr_t(pr_t&&)
prog.cc:12:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'int' to 'pr_t&&'
```

The compiler talked about something wrong with `p = new T(__VA_ARGS__);`. But shouldn't it not be considered at all when `::std::is_aggregate_v<T>` is true?

Note that a similar pattern using `if constexpr` with placement new has worked. Quoted from [cppref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_aggregate) example.

```
template<class T, class... Args>
T* construct(T* p, Args&&... args) {
    if constexpr(std::is_aggregate_v<T>) {
        return ::new (static_cast<void*>(p)) T{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
    }
    else {
        return ::new (static_cast<void*>(p)) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
}
```

I guess something is special about the non-placement version?

Comment: Why you try to use preprocessor macros in C++ anymore? If your code with constexpr if works, forget about all the macro stuff.

Comment: @Klaus I've updated the question. I do have a reason not to use a function template.

Comment: Whoops, hammered. The crux of the question is equivalent to that other one (using `if constexpr` outside of a template), but maybe the connection should be made in an answer here.

Comment: @Quentin I've added it to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with placement vs non-placement new. The issue arises due to your expansion of `__VA_ARGS__` in a macro instead of using perfect forwarding in a function. Here, the compiler still tries to compile (after expansion) `p = new pr_t(1, 2);` even though it will never be executed, which then fails. The reason for this is (as pointed out in the duplicate linked by Quentin) that discarded statements arising from `if constexpr` are only not instantiated in an enclosing template instantiation. As an easy demonstration, consider that this will fail as well:

```
#include <iostream>

struct pr_t {
  int a, b;
};

int main() {
  if constexpr (false) {
    pr_t* p = new pr_t(1, 2);
  }
}
```

If you use the non-placement new in a function analogously to the placement version, it works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T, class... Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> makeFunc(Args&&... args) {
  if constexpr (std::is_aggregate_v<T>) {
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T{std::forward<Args>(args)...});
  }
  else {
    return std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
}

struct Aggregate {
  int a, b;
};

class No_Aggregate {
  int a, b;
public:
  explicit No_Aggregate(int a, int b) : a{a}, b{b} {}
  auto get_a() {
    return a;
  }
  auto get_b() {
    return b;
  }
};

int main() {
  auto agg = makeFunc<Aggregate>(1, 2);
  std::cout << std::is_aggregate_v<Aggregate> << ' '
            << agg->a << ' ' << agg->b << '\n';
  auto n_agg = makeFunc<No_Aggregate>(3, 4);
  std::cout << std::is_aggregate_v<No_Aggregate> << ' ' 
            << n_agg->get_a() << ' ' << n_agg->get_b() << '\n';
}
```

Output:

> 1 1 2
>   0 3 4

Comment: So, it has to be implemented within a function template.

Comment: I guess so, yes.

Answer (score 2):

It's entirely because you are trying to expand `__VA_ARGS__` in a macro, rather than `std::forward<Args>(args)...` in a template.

```
template<class T, class... Args>
T* make(Args&&... args) {
    if constexpr(std::is_aggregate_v<T>) {
        return ::new T{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
    }
    else {
        return ::new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
}
```